# AttributeError:Float' object has no attribute log /TypeError: ufunc 'log' not supported for the input types

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, natural-logarithm

I have a series of fluorescence intensity data in a column ('2.4M').   I tried to create a new column 'ln_2.4M' by taking the ln of column '2.4M' I got an error:

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'

```
df["ln_2.4M"] = np.log(df["2.4M"])
```

I tried using a for loop to iterate the log over each fluorescence data in the column "2.4M":

```
ln2_4M = []
for x in df["2.4M"]:
    ln2_4M = np.log(x)
    print(ln2_4M)
```

Although it printed out ln2_4M as log of column "2.4M" correctly, I am unable to use the data because it gave alongside a TypeError:
ufunc 'log' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'

Not sure why? - Any help at understanding what is happening and how to fix this problem is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's `x`?  Or if you prefer `df.info()`?  You need to tell us the key informaiton about `df` and that column in particular.

Comment: My guess is that this column is object dtype.  `np.log(...)` of such a array/Series attempts to call the `log` method of the array's elements.  That usually fails since few object classes have a `log` method.  You might try converting the series to `float` dtype.

Comment: it would be helpful if you started with a brief intro to your problem.  "I have a Pandas DataFrame.  I would like to take the log of one column, ...".    That said, your problem is likely what has already been suggested. Have you tried using `df.dtypes` to see what you data types are in your columns?

Comment: Many thanks hpaulj and Donna. Apologies, I could have made my question more clearer. Yes you are both right - it was a problem of an object dtype that needed to be converted to a float dtype first before taking the log. However using astype.float() didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

.
I then tried using the method below and it worked:

```
df["2.4M"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2.4M"],errors = 'coerce')

df["ln_24M"] = np.log(df["2.4M"])
```